# How to have background between two handles of jQuery Slider using css gradient

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've just wached Lea Verou talk [CSS Variables: var(--subtitle);](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2an6-WVPuJU) and she give example to have gradient from 0 to slider handle, I need to have similar but between jQuery Slider handles:

```js
$(function() {
  var max = 400;
  var $slider = $('.slider');
  function set(a, b) {
    $slider[0].style.setProperty("--from", (a / max) * 100);
    $slider[0].style.setProperty("--to", (b / max) * 100);
  }
  set(100, 200);
  $slider.slider({
    values: [100, 200],
    min: 0,
    max: max,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      set.apply(null, ui.values);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.slider {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue calc(var(--from) * 1%), transparent 0, transparent 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution:

```js
$(function() {
  var max = 400;
  var $slider = $('.slider');
  function set(a, b) {
    $slider[0].style.setProperty("--from", (a / max) * 100);
    $slider[0].style.setProperty("--to", (b / max) * 100);
  }
  set(100, 200);
  $slider.slider({
    values: [100, 200],
    min: 0,
    max: max,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      set.apply(null, ui.values);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.slider {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent calc(var(--from) * 1%), red 0, red calc(var(--to) * 1%), transparent 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<div class="slider"></div>
```